# Rails and ajax file upload - cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image-uploading

I am developing a Rails app with a module for dynamic - ajax - image upload to gallery. I am doing it basing on [this app - multi-file-upload-demo](https://github.com/rounders/multi-file-upload-demo/). I am not very keen in Javascript and stuff, so I copy a lot of logic from that implementation.

I made up my app following all logic from rounders demo, I have included all gems and javascript libraries, and I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

in chrome console, which refers to tmpl.js file

```
tmpl.load = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
};
```

My knowledge of JS doesn't make it clear to me which piece of code triggers that function so I can go further.

Can you advise me what are the next steps to investigate source of this problem? I expect potential reasons may be various, so I don't want to paste all code from the application.

Answer (score 38):

This is old but I found an actual solution to this. Change your require in `application.js` to `//=require jquery-fileupload/basic` instead of `//= require jquery-fileupload`.

Comment: Thank you very much @BlakeWilliams!
This should be marked as correct response, btw...

Comment: It seems than now works, Now I have to check all functionality over fileupload is working... and I would like to know the difference between require  jquery-fileupload/basic and  jquery-fileupload ... to avoid surprises

Answer (score 20):

The reason you're getting this error is because you are missing a script tag id="template-upload" or id="template-download" or both.

Example from the Demo at: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-upload fade">
        <td class="preview"><span class="fade"></span></td>
        <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
        <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else if (o.files.valid && !i) { %}
            <td>
                <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
            </td>
            <td class="start">{% if (!o.options.autoUpload) { %}
                <button class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i>
                    <span>Start</span>
                </button>
            {% } %}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="cancel">{% if (!i) { %}
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="icon-ban-circle icon-white"></i>
                <span>Cancel</span>
            </button>
        {% } %}</td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
    <tr class="template-download fade">
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <td></td>
            <td class="name"><span>{%=file.name%}</span></td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td class="error" colspan="2"><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</td>
        {% } else { %}
            <td class="preview">{% if (file.thumbnail_url) { %}
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="gallery" download="{%=file.name%}"><img src="{%=file.thumbnail_url%}"></a>
            {% } %}</td>
            <td class="name">
                <a href="{%=file.url%}" title="{%=file.name%}" data-gallery="{%=file.thumbnail_url&&'gallery'%}" download="{%=file.name%}">{%=file.name%}</a>
            </td>
            <td class="size"><span>{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span></td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        {% } %}
        <td class="delete">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}"{% if (file.delete_with_credentials) { %} data-xhr-fields='{"withCredentials":true}'{% } %}>
                <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                <span>Delete</span>
            </button>
            <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

The UI version depends on both these templates being present.

I was having the same problem and decided to checkout what was missing.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 10):

I ran into this same problem as well. However, loading the basic version of the file-upload plugin was not an option for me since I use previewing for one upload, but not for the other. You can disable the "preview" functionality and the attempted processing of `template-upload` and `template-download` on a case-by-case basis by setting the `uploadTemplateId` and `downloadTemplateId` options for the file-upload plugin to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells us that `document.getElementById(id)` is returning `null`, so there is no element currently in the document with the specified `id.`

To debug, try adding a call to `console.log(id);` before the `return` statement. Once you do that you can find the value of `id` that is causing the problem.  Hopefully the error is the result of a simple typo, remember the value of `id` is case-sensitive. If a typo is not the problem, you can at least set a conditional breakpoint since you now know the value of `id` that you want to break on.  After hitting the breakpoint, it's just a matter of stepping through to the calling functions to "see which piece of code triggers that function."  Hope this helps.

Comment: this worked for me as i picked up a typo by looking at my script tag's id carefully

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this plugin for a few month, today i noticed that file upload didn't work, and i get an error

```
"cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null error".
```

I looked into it, and its because a simple reason.
the file path

```
http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.min.js
```

changed to

```
http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js
```

in the git of blueimp.
as you could see here

```
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
```

the path changed in this file.

```
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/index.html
```

I changed to the right path and its works.
hope this answer will help someone here that got same problem.