# s3 browser upload, canonical or policy bucket?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The docs for the latest sigv4 s3 browser upload post - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html
- show that I need to use `x-amz-signature`, `x-amz-credential`, and `policy`.

If I try that, I get an error saying that I'm missing `AWSAccessKeyId`, which is not mentioned in the docs, and that the `x-amz-signature` needs to be `signature`.

#### String to sign:

Am I supposed to be doing the base64 bucket policy doc above, or am I supposed to be doing the canonical approach, such as the python post to dynamoDB - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html#sig-v4-examples-post.

#### Signature:

the canonical uses hmac hexdigest `hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()`

The upload doc above uses hmac with base64: `Base64.encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', signaturekey,  @policy))`.

Under the [hood of the ruby sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/signers/v4.rb), it looks like they are using the non-hmac hexdigest: `OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, value)`.

Which method is needed to upload to s3?

FWIW, I'm using a SPA with Rails as an API, so I unfortunately don't have access to any rails view helpers.

I posted a question about my code [yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42592504/upload-file-to-s3-on-client-side-with-rails-carrierwave-direct-and-jquery-file), and unfortunately got shown a link that uses rails view helpers

### Edit:

What the policy is sending:

```
{"expiration":"2017-03-06T20:13:51Z",
 "conditions":[
     {"bucket":"example-development"},
     {"x-amz-credential":"AKIAIVVIZJHOBCBAB5CA/20170305/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request"},
     {"x-amz-algorithm":"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"},
     {"x-amz-date":"20170305T000000Z"}
    ]
 }
```

What the form is sending:

```
Policy:"eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNy0wMy0wNlQyMDoxOTowN1oiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJ3YXlkb3BlLWRldmVsb3BtZW50In0seyJ4LWFtei1jcmVkZW50aWFsIjoiQUtJQUlWVklaSkhPQkNCQUI1Q0EvMjAxNzAzMDUvdXMtd2VzdC0yL3MzL2F3czRfcmVxdWVzdCJ9LHsieC1hbXotYWxnb3JpdGhtIjoiQVdTNC1ITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJ9LHsieC1hbXotZGF0ZSI6IjIwMTcwMzA1VDAwMDAwMFoifV19"
X-Amz-Signature:"Cqjvo9aYCrb8PYHD+mUDjlOwKUzTpsI4d5/oycFAUBA="
key:"uploads/photo/photo/126/photo.jpg"
x-amz-algorithm:"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
x-amz-credential:"AKIAIVVIZJHOBCBAB5CA/20170305/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request"
x-amz-date:"20170305T000000Z"
```

The bucket policy and CORS contain zero conditions.

Comment: You need `X-Amz-Algorithm` with a value of `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` in your form and policy.  You didn't mention this, and if it's absent, that might trigger the message about `AWSAccessKeyId` (which you should not typically use).  And you shoud be using the policy document.

Comment: Updated with data that is being sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With an s3 browser upload, the string to sign should be the bucket config: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html

Follow the links at the bottom of the page.